# Android app crashes: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) (GLThread 7380)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hello my app crashes if I try to shot a projectile, but only between 1 - 2 seconds after the app launches. If i wait a few seconds it won't crash and it works perfect. On the desktop version it doesn't crash at all.

Error code:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x191d4 in tid 10103
>   (GLThread 7380)

It doesn't have to do something with destroying bodies when the world is locked because I do manage these with a delayed removal.

```
void shot(ProjectileData data) {
    this.data = data;

    if (data.elementType == ElementType.DARK) filter.groupIndex = FilterBits.DARK_GROUP;
    else filter.groupIndex = FilterBits.LIGHT_GROUP;
    fixture.setFilterData(filter);

    spawn(data.start);

    newNormal.set(data.normal).scl(SPEED_VEL * bodyC.body.getMass() / (1/60.0f));
    bodyC.body.applyForceToCenter(newNormal, true);
}

public void spawn(float x, float y) {
    bodyC.body.setActive(true);
    bodyC.body.setTransform(x, y, bodyC.body.getAngle());
}
```

EDIT:

Testet devices:

- SGS5 -> chrash
- SGS7 egde -> chrash
- LG G4 -> chrash

Comment: Do you use any native libraries? If not it's probably a bug in the OpenGL implementation on the device. Does it happen with other devices (from another manufacturer) as well?

Comment: LibGDX has the box2d native lib. I testet it now with an SGS5 and SGS7 edge. Both crashed

Comment: Try commenting out one line at a time starting from the last line and see where the crash happens.